# scope variable in javascript

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I use this plugin
http://plugins.upbootstrap.com/bootstrap-ajax-typeahead/
to have typeahead function on a web page.

I have to text box.

One for brand card and the other one is for models car.

I type To, it will display me Toyota

when toyota is selected, i would like to see echo, matrix....

so i set a variable brandId to get the value selected, but value returned in the ulr is

http://localhost:8080/brands/undefined/models?query=ech

but i brandId = 1 in the watch exression before the url is shown.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var brandId;

    $("#brand").typeahead({
        onSelect: function(item) {
            debugger;
            console.log(item);
            //enable component
            $("#model").removeAttr("disabled");
            brandId = item.value;

        },
        ajax: {
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/brands',
            valueField: "brandId",
            displayField: "brand"
        }
    });

    $("#model").typeahead({
        ajax: {
            url: '/brands/' + brandId + '/models',
            valueField: "modelId",
            displayField: "model"
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: shouldn't `valueField: "brandId",` be `valueField: brandId,`? also you can remove the line `var brandId;`, if you assign a unknown variable in a function, it becomes a global variable automagically.

Comment: tried to change the valueField value, but get same result. I get brandId is not defined in the url property

Comment: @cari It's bad practice to rely on globals, and very bad practice to do so without warning future users or maintainers of your code. Better to explicitly declare them as globals (and comment them as such). Failing that, an object to hold your modules scope would be better.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are instantiating your `#model` typeahead with a URL that is composed one time. Once `url` is assigned to `'/brands/' + <current value of brand ID> + '/models'`, you never reassign it.

Try refactoring your typeahead assignment into a separate function that you can call with the new value of `brandId` when the user selects it:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var initModelTypeahead = function(brandId) {
      $("#model").typeahead({
          ajax: {
              url: '/brands/' + brandId + '/models',
              valueField: "modelId",
              displayField: "model"
          }
      });
  };

  $("#brand").typeahead({
      onSelect: function(item) {
          debugger;
          console.log(item);
          //enable component
          $("#model").removeAttr("disabled");
          initModelTypeahead(item.value);
      },
      ajax: {
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/brands',
          valueField: "brandId",
          displayField: "brand"
      }
  });

});
```

Comment: Try changing your `#brand` AJAX URL to `/brands` instead of specifying the host. You may be hitting a same origin policy violation.

Comment: that don't fix the model ajax call... is never done, but the one for brand is ok